# Programmatically Segue Between Views in Different Storyboard Files

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a view `HostViewController` in `Host.storyboard` and, in storyboard I am able to segue to `AttendDetailViewController` in `Main.storyboard`.   However, I want to do this programmatically as follows:

```
private func attendDetailViewControllerSegue(event: CAEvent) {
    let vc = AttendDetailViewController(nibName: "AttendDetailViewController", bundle: nil)
    vc.event = event

    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

However, when I run this I get the following error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle ... with name 'AttendDetailViewController''

I have tried every solution on the internet for this problem, and I feel it might have something to do with the Views being in different storyboards.

Any thoughts on how to do this segue without an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- to load from xib ( used when there is AttendDetailViewController.xib file in your project )

```
 let vc  = AttendDetailViewController(nibName: "AttendDetailViewController", bundle: nil)
```

2- to load from storyboard ( used when the vc is inside a storyboard )

```
 let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Host", bundle: nil)!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vciD") as? AttendDetailViewController
```

3-  load programmatically ( used when the vc layout is created programmatically )

```
let vc = AttendDetailViewController()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the storyboard from the bundle:

```
var hostStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Host", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

Then, instantiate and present the view controller:

```
let someViewController = hostStoryboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AttendDetailViewController") as? AttendDetailViewController
self.navigationController?.present(attendDetailViewController!, animated: true)
```

Don't forget to set the `AttendDetailViewController`'s storyboard identifier in the storyboard.

---

I also recommend you safely unwrap `attendDetailViewController` before using it:

```
let someViewController = hostStoryboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AttendDetailViewController") as? AttendDetailViewController
if let vc = attendDetailViewController {
    self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true)
}
```